# Where are the properties/methods like parseInt and parseFloat defined?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, global-object

```js
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('parseInt'));  // false
console.log(Number.prototype.hasOwnProperty('parseInt'));  // false
```

Where is parseInt defined if not on the default prototype object (Object.prototype), the prototype object from which all JS objects inherit?

Comment: `global`, aka `window` (in the DOM in web-browsers) - run `typeof window.parseInt` in your browser's devtools console to see for yourself.

Comment: The `prototype` of `Object` is not `window`, that's why.

Comment: @Dai But why can't I use something like `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object).hasOwnProperty('parseInt')` to verify it's existence on global ?

Comment: Because `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object)` **is not** `window`. (The expression `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object)` actually returns a `Function` object, which is the built-in `Object` ctor function)

Comment: @noSelf Can you explain why you believe that this _should_ work? Because you seem to be mixing up different concepts.

Comment: @Ivar hmm. So if I understand it correctly, we have a global object which is everywhere in the JS program. Then we have the built in Object constructor, Function constructor, Array constructor etc with their own prototypes (containing methods like forEach etc) `within` this global object ?

Comment: @noSelf_ Pretty much yes. The prototypes are a mechanism that allows objects to inherit features form other objects. The functions that are in the prototype of `Number` can directly be called on numbers, like `1.1.toFixed(2)`. This works because `.toFixed()` exists on the `Number.prototype`. You don't call `parseInt()` on a number like `(1).parseInt('123')`. See [Object prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) on MDN.

Comment: @Ivar Thanks for the reply. Just out of curiosity. Is there a way to make `Number` type inherit the `parseInt()` from global ?

Comment: You can assign the `parseInt` function to the `Number` prototype with `Number.prototype.parseInt = parseInt`. Though it doesn't make much sense because you already need to have an instance of a number type, which defeats the purpose of parsing one. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ozu4hj8g/

Comment: @Ivar Aha... learnt something new today `Number.prototype.parseInt = parseInt`. Although this particular eg is not useful :) but still might come in handy sometime. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @noSelf_ I do want to point out that it is [generally considered bad practice to extend the prototype of build-in objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice). There are useful applications, such as [polyfills](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill), but in general it can cause bugs that are very hard to discover.

Answer (score 1):

Both `parseInt` and `parseFloat` are native code, so they will depend on the implementation. Neither function has a prototype.

Somewhere in [this commit](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/40817d22428a66c4de194ac95cd1ebac111d9c84), there are some definitions for GlobalParseInt and GlobalParseFloat. If you have knowledge of C/natives, you could take a look and learn for yourself. As for Spidermonkey, Firefox's engine, I couldn't find an exact file but did find many references to the `parseInt` function in [this search](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/search?q=parseInt).